# jquery chaining custom events and animations

Tags: jquery, events, chaining

I need to chain events in jquery and i am not sure if i chain them correctly, because i want to trigger a custom event with a animation and if the animation is done i need to trigger another event.

this code works, console.log('open is done!') is fired after 5000ms:

```
$.when(
    // Open
    $('a').animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete
    })
).done(function() {
    console.log('open is done!');
    $('a.open').trigger('close');
});
```

but i want to put the animation in another custom event, wait until the event is finished and trigger the other custom event, such as:

```
$.when(
    // Open
    $('a').trigger('open')
).done(function() {
    console.log('open is done!');
    $('a.open').trigger('close');
});

$(document).on('open', function(event) {
    // Open
    $('a').animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
});
```

console.log('open is done!') is fired suddenly, how do i have to chain the events correctly?

thanks in advance

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('a').trigger('open')

    $(document).on('open', function(event) {
          $('a').animate({
                  width: "100%"
                }, 5000, function() {
                    console.log('open is done!');
                    $('a.open').trigger('close');
          });
    });
```